# How long does NAT keep a TCP translation field in it's table?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, p2p

I was wondering if I could create a TCP client on machine A and connect it to a remote host (S) and then close the connection from client side and create a TCP listener on the on the same machine (machine A) with the same port that was used for client(say port 1234). the server which now has the A's Endpoint , sends it to another machine (B) and B can connect to A on A's public Endpoint(say port 4567) and the NAT on A's network redirect the SYN to A because it still has the translation(4567 -> 1234) in it's table.
I want to know how much time is there between disconnecting the first connection and connecting of the node B.

Comment: This is a) not a programming question, and b) entirely implementation-dependent. "NAT" is a technology, not a specification. The technique you describe fall under the broader category of "port tunneling"; it may work with specific routers, but often will not, because of timeouts as well as stateful maintenance of the table (if the router detects that the connection was in fact closed, it may well remove the mapping from its table). If you want control over port forwarding, use UPnP, which _is_ a specification and well-supported.

Answer (score 1):

I agree wtih Peter Duniho's comment. But I am answering your question with usual NAT behavior.

What you want to do will not work. NAT doesn't behave same with both UDP and TCP protocol. What you said will work if the protocol was UDP and the NAT type of A was full cone.

**Why for TCP won't work**

NAT allows incoming SYN from a IP:Port if a SYN was sent previously through the NAT to that IP:Port. And these two incoming and outgoing SYN must cross each other outside the NAT. If before outgoing SYN crosses the NAT the incoming SYN arrives, then NAT will drop the packet and may send RST message as reply. This procedure is called [TCP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching).

This hole punching will not work on all NATs. For this to work NAT needs support simultaneous open connection.

**How long does NAT keep a TCP translation field in it's table**

The translation may get timed out and this time out value is totally implementation dependent. Also NAT can receive a TCP RST message and remove the binding.

So bottom line is its hard to define NAT behavior in general as this has no specified protocol. You have to do experiments and find out for yourself.